# Почему Klaxon не парсит HashMap?

Tags: kotlin

Есть json:

```
{date: 12123123123, prices: [1, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Так не работает:

```
val json = Klaxon().parse<HapMap<String, Any>>(content)
```

А так работает.

```
val json = Klaxon().parse<Map<String, Any>>(content)
```

**Это баг Klaxon или я что-то не пониманию в HashMap?**

*Так же будут благодарен совету что лучше всего использовать для парсинга json в котлине.*

Comment: Вот тут об этом: https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon/issues/103

Что лучше всего не зною, но с нуля я бы начал с этого: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` - это одна из реализаций интерфейса `Map`. В данном случае не нужно явно указывать класс, достаточно указать интерфейс. Klaxon сам знает какой класс выбрать:

```
import com.beust.klaxon.Klaxon

fun main() {
    val content = "{\"date\": 12123123123, \"prices\": [1, 3, 4, 5]}"
    val json = Klaxon().parse<Map<String, Any>>(content)
    println(json)  // Выводим результат парсинга
    println(json!!::class.simpleName)  // Выводим класс, к которому относится результат
}
```

Вывод:

```
{date=12123123123, prices=JsonArray(value=[1, 3, 4, 5])}
HashMap
```